# is there a way to make a single world bold in a paragraph without appending?

Tags: html

```html
<p>Next word is bold</p><strong><p>Bold</p></strong>
```

but the paragraphs are separated how could i combine theses into one like this

"Next Word Is Bold **Bold**"

within the use of javascript?

Comment: `<p>Next word is bold <strong>Bold</strong></p>` Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What html, none of it is 'Invalid' if it worked correctly as intended to.

Comment: Inline elements like `strong` shouldn't wrap block elements like `p`, it should be the other way around. Practically, you can, and you can also style an inline element to behave like a block element and vice versa but it would still technically be considered "invalid" html.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p>Next word is bold <strong>Bold</strong></p>
```

Is that what you're looking for?
–
artie